# wrt54g routing table / ip table

Tags: c, linux, routes, embedded, openwrt

I am an Undergraduate Student developing a firmware upgrade for the wrt54GL router which concerns its routing table. The aim of the implementation is to enhance the routing of IPv4 and IPv6.

The question is what are the modules that I need to look into so that I could alter the routing table's source/ configuration to my requirements?

I have already setup the development environment on ubuntu with netbeans the openwrt toolchain.

I am new to this and any advice or reading material on this would be rally helpful as I have failed to find any useful material online.

The link I used to router source is as follows,
http://support.linksys.com/en-apac/gplcodecenter

and the source code file name that i downloaded is as follows,
`WRT54GL-US_v4.30.16.004.tar`

Your help would be really appreciated as this implementation is vital for my degree.

Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be using linux version 2.4.20. The kernel subdirectory net/ipv4 has the core ipv4 code. Files route.c and the fib_*.c files contain the main route handling code. See
http://www.cs.unh.edu/cnrg/people/gherrin/linux-net.html#tth_chAp8. This reference is a little old, but so is your kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. I will check this and post back :)